# How do I add Sort by options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a 'Sort By' dropdown on an events page where users can view a number of events and I'd like to allow users to Sort the events by Name (Alphebetical), Date (Created_At), and perhaps (Number of people attending hi/low).

How can I achieve this? I'm guessing with a default scope: order, Event.where(:name, ASC) for example but i'm not sure as I've never done this before.. Also how would I display/use the scope in the dropdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommed you the very-usefull gem has_scope: 
https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope

What you could do with it:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope ordered, lambda do |attribute, order|
    return where("FALSE") unless self.attribute_names.include?(attribute.to_s)
    order(attribute.to_sym, order.to_sym
  end


class EventsController < ApplicationController
  has_scope :ordered do |controller, scope, value|
    scope.ordered(value, :desc)
  end

# view
options = [['Name', 'name'], ['Date', 'date']]
select_tag("ordered", options_for_select(options, selected: params[:ordered]), onchange: "window.location.href = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '?ordered=' + $(this).val();"
```

I did not test the view, you might have to change the code a little bit. The javascript redirect does not support extra GET params!

Comment: AWESOME!!! Would you mind sharing how I would implement this in the view? Thanks so much!

Comment: I added an example @SonnyBlack

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the RailsCasts

http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

This also includes `pagination` and simple searches. However, you can take from it the part that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For active record you just need to append .order(symbol) to your active record query.

for alphabetic you could do.

```
Object.where(ARRGUMENT).order(:name)
```

or for all

```
Object.order(:name)
```

You don't need to use a scope for this it is over kill for something this simple.

If you want to create an interactive table then you might want to consider a Javascript solution. This is the one that has worked the best for me.

https://datatables.net/

I have used and currently use this gem with great success.

https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails